# Transferir foco de uma célula JTable logo após digitar horário

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Olá, estou utilizando uma `JTable` para digitação de cartão de ponto. Preciso de ajuda nisso, mas já dei uma pesquisada e nada me ajudou muito. Já tentei fazer isso de várias maneiras e não consegui.

Tenho diversas batidas (entradas e saídas) no cartão de ponto e, todos eles são de horários (`"##:##"`). Atualmente estou transferindo o foco para um `JFormattedTextField` que contém essa máscara e, faço uma verificação, quando está com `length.trim() == 5` e o `caretPosition == 5`, eu mudo o foco para a próxima célula. Mas esse método está ultrapassado - como estou programando para uma empresa, tal empresa requer que seja a `JTable` editável, ou crie uma interface para melhor digitação dessas bases. entretanto, a `JTable` editável fica mais bonito, e esse método está "travando" meu sistema, ou seja, não consigo evoluir a facilidade do cartão de ponto por causa disso - além de ficar bem feia a interface do projeto.

A dúvida: como fazer um `JFormattedTextField` dentro da célula, de forma que tenha essa "máscara" que quando termina de digitar, muda o foco?

O que eu já tentei:

- Já criei um `JFormattedTextField` e adicionei como `defaultCellEditor` (ou  `defaultCellRenderer`) para cada coluna.
- Problema: quando eu transferia o foco para a célula de baixo, ele tratava como se fosse apenas 1 `JFormattedTextField`, ou seja, a verificação caía como true para a célula que estava em cima. Além disso, conforme ia digitando, mudava o valor para todas as células que continha aquele `JFormattedTextField`.
- Solução nesse caso: se houver uma maneira de adicionar um `List<JFormattedTextField>` como cellRenderer (ou cellEditor) para uma célula em específico ao invés de uma coluna inteira.
- O que eu tentei: Sei que esse método que vou descrever, é muita gambiarra e, não segue nem um pouco os princípios da boa prática de programação, mas o mesmo `JFormattedTextField` que eu estava transferindo o foco da `JTable` para ele, ou vice-versa, tentei mudar toda a tela para `setBounds` e usar isso nele, usando o `getCellRect(row, col, true)` para pegar o local correto.
- O problema: o `TextField` ficava para trás da `JTable`, e eu não encontrei um método para colocar ele de volta acima, além do código ficar mais extenso e, ficar muito deselegante a interface (porque realmente é uma gambiarra).

Agradeço quem puder me ajudar, faz tempo que estou quebrando a cabeça com isso!

[image: imagem]
[image: imagem2]
[image: imagem3]
[image: imagem4]

Basicamente começa na entrada 1, assim que termina de digitar o horário, ele passa para o 2, e digitando o 2, vai pro 3, e assim por diante, e quando chegar no último, ele muda de linha e vai para a entrada 1 da próxima linha.

Meu Model:

```
@Override
public String getColumnName(int col) {
    return colName.get(col);
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return colName.size();
}

@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
    return String.class;
}

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    if (first) {
        Date adm = new Date();
        Date dem = new Date();
        try {
            dateAdm.setTime(sdf.parse(datAdm));
            dateDem.setTime(sdf.parse(datDem));
            adm = sdf.parse(datAdm);
            dem = sdf.parse(datDem);
        } catch (Exception E) {
            E.printStackTrace();
        }
        int dias = stT.dataDiff(adm, dem) + 1;
        this.first = false;
        return dias;
    } else {
        return lCard.size();
    }
}
```

Tem o `getValueAt` e o `setValueAt` também, mas resolvi não postar porque são grandes demais.

Meu `DefaultTableCellRenderer`:

```
class celRenderModel extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

/**
 *
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

ModelCartao mCard;

public celRenderModel(ModelCartao mc) {
    this.mCard = mc;
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    Color c = Color.WHITE;
    if (mCard.isCor(row)) {//Verifica se é para pintar ou não (funcionando perfeitamente!)
        c = Color.GREEN;
        setBackground(c);
    } else {
        c = Color.WHITE;
        setBackground(c);
    }
    return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
}
}
```

Encontrei em um backup antigo do meu sistema, o meu `CellEditor`, caso ajude:

```
public class EditarCelulaTabela extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {
    JComponent component = new JTextField();
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, int rowIndex, int vColIndex) {
        ((JTextField) component).setText((String) value);
        addCellEditorListener(new CellEditorListener() {
            @Override
            public void editingCanceled(ChangeEvent e0) {
                System.out.println("Cancelou");
            }

            @Override
            public void editingStopped(ChangeEvent e1) {
                if(((JTextField)component).getText().trim().length()!=5){
                    component.requestFocus();
                    System.out.println("Parou!");
                }
            }
        });

        // Retorna a configuracao do componente  
        return component;
    }

    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        System.out.println(((JTextField) component).getText());               
        return ((JTextField) component).getText();
    }

    public EditarCelulaTabela(final JTextField tf) {
        component = tf;
    }

}
```

Caso precise de mais alguma informação, só avisar!

Comment: `mas esse método está ultrapassado` -  o que isso significa?

Comment: vou editar, para melhor compreensão!

Comment: Cara, uma dica, tem muito texto ai desnecessário, foque-se apenas no problema enfrentado. Eu até entendi seu problema, mas o texto longo acabou confundindo.

Comment: Pelo que entendi você tem uma tabela com colunas de horas editaveis, e quer que seja aplicada mascara nas células e, ao ser preenchida, quer que o foco seja passado pra seguinte. Correto?

Comment: exato, mas preciso de dinâmica para fazer isso (porque a JTable vai ter algumas funcionalidades que não vem ao caso no momento), quis explicar o mais detalhado possível justamente para entender melhor, desculpa o excesso, se puder ajudar, qualquer dúvida só falar!

Comment: Fiz algo parecido, mas esse mudar de foco ai acho que não é interessante não hein. Você utiliza seu proprio TableModel? Se sim, tudo fica mais facil.

Comment: Sim, tenho meu próprio Model, usando o método Abstract! vou fazer umas imagens aqui para melhor explicar, aí vou postar a funcionalidade que eu quero ok?

Comment: Adicione, se tiver, o código do seu CellRenderer e cellEditor, alem do seu tablemodel.

Comment: cara, podemos ir para o chat, porque é complicado esse sistema, vai ficar algo gigantesco aqui no tópico

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40843/discussion-between-thomas-braz-pinto-and-diegofm).

Comment: Poderia ser ao pressionar TAB? Precisa obrigatoriamente ser automatico ao preencher o campo todo?

Comment: Não pode ser ao pressionar tab, tem sim que transferir ao final da digitação, porque como eu disse, imagina que você tem 10 batidas por dia, durante 5 anos, você precisa de agilidade para não ficar tanto tempo fazendo isso (tem dias que a galera aqui tem uns 20 processos de 5meses a 20 anos aqui), por isso preciso que seja na hora que o usuário terminou de digitar tudo a transferência, o tab já é padrão, dá para usar ele automaticamente, mas ele vai "reduzir a eficiência" do que eu preciso

Comment: Bom, não vejo essa dificuldade toda em apertar tab a cada campo, é uma solução menos complexa que facilita a chance de uma resposta que atenda e que já até achei no soen pronta.

Comment: Se encontrar alguma coisa, posto aqui.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Foi bem difícil de fazer, mas eu consegui. **:D**

O código que se segue abaixo é completo, compilável, testável e executável. Inclui, em meio às devidas explicações, o código completo de todas as classes (até mesmo os `imports`). Assim sendo, outras pessoas poderão testar e reaproveitar isso.

O seu problema é com campos do tipo hora. Porém, para ter certeza que a minha solução é boa, eu solucionei o problema com campos dos tipos horas, datas e CPF, além de deixar aberto o caminho para implementar com quaisquer outros formatos necessários. Os campos com esses formatos da `JTable` têm as seguintes características nesta implementação:

- São dados com máscaras. `##:##` é usado para horas, `##/##/####` para datas e `###.###.###-##` para CPFs. Ele nunca deixa a máscara ser sobrescrita ou apagada.
- Devido ao uso da máscara, ele não deixa que caracteres inválidos sejam digitados.
- A `JTable` não deixa você sair do campo de edição se o conteúdo dele não for nem válido e nem totalmente em branco. No caso das horas, ele vai verificar se a hora está entre 00 e 23 e se os minutos estão entre 00 e 59. Nas datas, ele vai verificar se os meses são de 30 ou 31 dias e vai verificar se o ano é bissexto ou não no 29 de fevereiro. No campo CPF, o cálculo dos dígitos verificadores será efetuado.
- Após você terminar de digitar um destes campos com um valor válido (e apenas com um valor válido), ele automaticamente pula para o campo seguinte sem que você precise clicar ou pressionar TAB.

Primeiro, vamos começar com nossas classes para representar dados simples. Neste caso, horas, datas e CPFs.

Arquivo `Hora.java`:

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

/**
 * @author Victor Stafusa
 */
public final class Hora {

    private final int horas;
    private final int minutos;

    public static Hora parse(String formatado) {
        try {
            int[] parts = Stream.of(formatado.split(":")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
            if (parts.length != 2) return null;
            return new Hora(parts[0], parts[1]);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Hora(int horas, int minutos) {
        if (horas < 0 || horas > 23 || minutos < 0 || minutos > 59) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.horas = horas;
        this.minutos = minutos;
    }

    public int getHoras() {
        return horas;
    }

    public int getMinutos() {
        return minutos;
    }

    // Não estou usando o toString() para você poder ver que não preciso confiar na existência de um toString() em sua classe.
    public String converte() {
        return String.format("%02d:%02d", horas, minutos);
    }
}
```

Arquivo `Data.java`:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

/**
 * @author Victor Stafusa
 */
public final class Data {

    private final int dia;
    private final int mes;
    private final int ano;

    public static Data parse(String formatado) {
        try {
            int[] parts = Stream.of(formatado.split("/")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
            if (parts.length != 3) return null;
            return new Data(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Data(int dia, int mes, int ano) {
        if (dia <= 0 || dia > 31 || mes <= 0 || mes > 12 || ano < 1583 || ano > 9999) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        if (dia == 31 && Arrays.asList(2, 4, 6, 9, 11).contains(mes)) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        if (dia == 30 && mes == 2) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        if (dia == 29 && mes == 2 && (ano % 4 != 0 || Arrays.asList(100, 200, 300).contains(ano % 400))) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.dia = dia;
        this.mes = mes;
        this.ano = ano;
    }

    public int getDia() {
        return dia;
    }

    public int getMes() {
        return mes;
    }

    public int getAno() {
        return ano;
    }

    // Não estou usando o toString() para você poder ver que não preciso confiar na existência de um toString() em sua classe.
    public String converte() {
        return String.format("%02d/%02d/%04d", dia, mes, ano);
    }
}
```

Arquivo `Cpf.java`:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * @author Victor Stafusa
 */
public final class Cpf {

    private static final Pattern REGEX = Pattern.compile("^\\d{3}\\.\\d{3}\\.\\d{3}\\-\\d{2}$");
    private final String digitos;

    public static Cpf parse(String formatado) {
        try {
            return new Cpf(formatado);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Cpf(String digitos) {
        if (!REGEX.matcher(digitos).matches()) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        String d2 = digitos.replaceAll("\\.|\\-", "");
        int[] numeros = new int[11];
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            numeros[i] = d2.charAt(i) - '0';
        }
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            a += (i + 1) * numeros[i];
            b += (11 - i) * numeros[i];
        }
        a = a % 11 % 10;
        b += 2 * a;
        b = b * 10 % 11 % 10;
        if (a != numeros[9] || b != numeros[10]) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.digitos = digitos;
    }

    public String getDigitos() {
        return digitos;
    }
}
```

Estas três classes aí em cima são beans relativamente simples. Entretanto, note que cada uma delas têm um método estático `parse(String)` que retorna uma instância da classe se a `String` do parâmetro for válida ou `null` se não for, o que será útil mais adiante na nossa `CellEditor`.

A lógica que decide se os dados são ou não válidos está nos construtores, de forma a impossibilitar que instâncias inválidas possam ser criadas. Entretanto, essa lógica poderia estar em algum outro lugar caso fosse preciso, pois o que importa para a `CellEditor` (que será explanada abaixo) é que o método estático retorne uma instância apenas quando esta for válida, retornando `null` em caso contrário. Além disso, note que estas classes são imutáveis, para evitar-se que instâncias válidas possam se tornar inválidas futuramente, ou mesmo mudarem de um estado válido para outro, mas em um momento inoportuno.

Para a `JTable`, cada linha é representada por uma instância de alguma classe qualquer. Neste exemplo, eu tenho cada linha com cinco colunas, denominadas de `campo1`, `hora`, `campo2`, `data` e `cpf`. As colunas `campo1` e `campo2` são só colunas normais com o comportamento padrão, enquanto que as outras três são as nossas colunas especiais. Estes campos de cada linha estão armazenados na classe `MeuElemento`, que nada mais é do que um bean bem simples com getters e setters sem nada de especial.

Eis o arquivo `MeuElemento.java`:

```
/**
 * @author Victor Stafusa
 */
public class MeuElemento {

    private String campo1;
    private String campo2;
    private Hora hora;
    private Data data;
    private Cpf cpf;

    public MeuElemento() {
    }

    public String getCampo1() {
        return campo1;
    }

    public void setCampo1(String campo1) {
        this.campo1 = campo1;
    }

    public String getCampo2() {
        return campo2;
    }

    public void setCampo2(String campo2) {
        this.campo2 = campo2;
    }

    public Hora getHora() {
        return hora;
    }

    public void setHora(Hora hora) {
        this.hora = hora;
    }

    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Cpf getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(Cpf cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }
}
```

Tendo então a classe `MeuElemento` que representa cada uma das linhas, podemos então criar uma lista de elementos e com ela construir a nossa `TableModel`. Eis então o arquivo `MeuTableModel.java`:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

/**
 * @author Victor Stafusa
 */
public class MeuTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final List<MeuElemento> elementos;

    public MeuTableModel(List<MeuElemento> elementos) {
        this.elementos = elementos;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return elementos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        return new String[]{"Nome 1", "Horas", "Nome 2", "Data", "CPF"}[columnIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return new Class<?>[]{String.class, Hora.class, String.class, Data.class, Cpf.class}[columnIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        MeuElemento elemento = elementos.get(rowIndex);
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                return elemento.getCampo1();
            case 1:
                return elemento.getHora();
            case 2:
                return elemento.getCampo2();
            case 3:
                return elemento.getData();
            case 4:
                return elemento.getCpf();
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        MeuElemento elemento = elementos.get(rowIndex);
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                elemento.setCampo1((String) aValue);
                break;
            case 1:
                elemento.setHora((Hora) aValue);
                break;
            case 2:
                elemento.setCampo2((String) aValue);
                break;
            case 3:
                elemento.setData((Data) aValue);
                break;
            case 4:
                elemento.setCpf((Cpf) aValue);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
    }
}
```

Tendo a `TableModel`, nosso próximo passo é a `CellRenderer`. Portanto, segue-se o arquivo `MeuCellRenderer.java`:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

/**
 * @author Victor Stafusa
 */
public class MeuCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final ModelCartao mCard;

    public MeuCellRenderer(ModelCartao mCard) {
        this.mCard = mCard;
    }

    @Override
    protected void setValue(Object value) {
        setText(value == null ? ""
                : value instanceof Hora ? ((Hora) value).converte()
                : value instanceof Data ? ((Data) value).converte()
                : value instanceof Cpf ? ((Cpf) value).getDigitos()
                : value.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        Color c = mCard.isCor(row) ? Color.GREEN : Color.WHITE;
        setBackground(c);
        return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    }
}
```

O método `setValue(Object)` é o responsável por preencher o valor a ser exibido de acordo com o objeto referente a célula que será obtido da `TableModel`. Por causa disso, esse método acaba sendo o responsável por converter o valor (seja ele de qual classe for) para a representação em `String` que o mostrará na tela.

Observe que mantive a mesma lógica sua para escolher se a célula é branca ou verde. Como não sei o que a sua classe `ModelCartao` faz e nem o critério que ela usa para decidir a cor da célula, decidi então colocar uma implementação minimalista dela para que você então substitua pela implementação que você quiser. Esse é o meu arquivo `ModelCartao.java`:

```
public class ModelCartao {
    public boolean isCor(int row) {
        return row % 2 == 0; // Use o critério que você achar melhor.
    }
}
```

Feito isso tudo, agora é que vem a parte mais difícil e trabalhosa. Chegamos na nossa `CellEditor`. Eis então o arquivo `MeuCellEditor.java`:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

/**
 * @author Victor Stafusa
 */
public class MeuCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextComponent component;
    private int colunaEditando;
    private int linhaEditando;

    public MeuCellEditor() {
        this.colunaEditando = -1;
        this.linhaEditando = -1;
    }

    private boolean celulaHora() {
        return colunaEditando == 1;
    }

    private boolean celulaData() {
        return colunaEditando == 3;
    }

    private boolean celulaCpf() {
        return colunaEditando == 4;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopCellEditing() {
        boolean vazio = component.getText().replaceAll(":|_| |\\/|\\-|\\.", "").isEmpty();
        if (!vazio && getCellEditorValue() == null) return false;
        return super.stopCellEditing();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return celulaHora() ? Hora.parse(component.getText())
                : celulaData() ? Data.parse(component.getText())
                : celulaCpf() ? Cpf.parse(component.getText())
                : component.getText();
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        this.colunaEditando = column;
        this.linhaEditando = row;
        if (celulaHora()) {
            component = campoHora();
            if (value instanceof Hora) component.setText(((Hora) value).converte());
        } else if (celulaData()) {
            component = campoData();
            if (value instanceof Data) component.setText(((Data) value).converte());
        } else if (celulaCpf()) {
            component = campoCpf();
            if (value instanceof Cpf) component.setText(((Cpf) value).getDigitos());
        } else {
            component = new JTextField();
            if (value != null) component.setText(String.valueOf(value));
        }
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> component.requestFocusInWindow());
        return component;
    }

    private static Robot ROBOT;

    private synchronized static Robot obterRobot() {
        if (ROBOT == null) {
            try {
                ROBOT = new Robot();
            } catch (AWTException e) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(e);
            }
        }
        return ROBOT;
    }

    private static JFormattedTextField campoMascara(String mascara, int posicaoFinal, Predicate<String> teste) {
        Robot robot = obterRobot();
        MaskFormatter formatter;
        try {
            formatter = new MaskFormatter(mascara);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
        formatter.setValidCharacters("0123456789");
        formatter.setPlaceholderCharacter('_');
        JFormattedTextField jftf = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
        jftf.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                if (jftf.getCaretPosition() == posicaoFinal && teste.test(jftf.getText().replace("_", "") + String.valueOf(e.getKeyChar()))) {
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            }
        });
        return jftf;
    }

    private static JFormattedTextField campoHora() {
        return campoMascara("##:##", 4, x -> Hora.parse(x) != null);
    }

    private static JFormattedTextField campoData() {
        return campoMascara("##/##/####", 9, x -> Data.parse(x) != null);
    }

    private static JFormattedTextField campoCpf() {
        return campoMascara("###.###.###-##", 13, x -> Cpf.parse(x) != null);
    }
}
```

Este arquivo demanda maiores explicações:

1. Primeiramente, a `CellEditor` mantém os campos `colunaEditando` e `linhaEditando` para saber qual é a célula da `JTable` que está sendo editada a fim de descobrir o tipo de componente mais apropriado para a edição. Tal componente é armazenado no campo `component` quando este tornar-se disponível (inicialmente é `null`).
2. Os métodos `celulaHora()`, `celulaData()` e `celulaCpf()` servem para identificar qual é o tipo da célula do componente que está sendo editado. A lógica destes métodos é simples, e consiste apenas em verificar um número fixo de coluna, mas para algumas `JTable`s complicadas que você for fazer no mundo real, certamente haverá casos em que isso não será algo tão simples assim.
3. O método `stopCellEditing()` é fundamental. Ele é que é o método responsável por prender a edição na célula (ao retornar `false`) se o conteúdo dado na entrada não estiver preenchido corretamente sem estar em branco. O `replaceAll(":|_| |\\/|\\-|\\.", "")` é a parte que elimina os caracteres especiais da máscara, onde `":|_| |\\/|\\-|\\."` quer dizer "*dois pontos ou sublinhado ou espaço em branco ou barra ou traço ou ponto*". A ideia é que o `stopCellEditing()` só retorne `true` se o campo ou estiver preenchido de forma adequada ou esteja em branco, retornando `false` em caso contrário (ou seja, se preenchido de forma parcial, incompleta e/ou inválida). Assim sendo, o usuário não poderá deixar este campo preenchido de forma incorreta ou parcial, forçando um preechimento que ou seja válido ou deixe o campo vazio.
4. O método `getCellEditorValue()` é o responsável por obter o objeto (não necessariamente uma `String`) representado pela célula em edição. No nosso caso, além de `String`, ele pode retornar `Hora`, `Data` ou `Cpf`.
5. O método `getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable, Object, boolean, int, int)` é o responsável por criar o componente de edição do `CellEditor`. É ele também que registra qual é a célula que está sendo editada. É importante se notar que este método não reutiliza componentes de uma célula para outra, descartando-os quando ocorrer uma mudança da célula escolhida (e isso é de propósito). Caso contrário, é possível obter-se alguns bugs de fazer os valores de uma célula começarem a ser incorretamente copiados em outras células quando o componente é reutilizado.
6. O `EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> component.requestFocusInWindow())` é um workaround importante, pois por vezes um campo começa a receber digitação sem estar com o foco, o que causaria problemas para pular sozinho para o próximo campo depois sem precisar do TAB. Com essa <s>gambiarra</s>, humm, ops quero dizer... **técnica especial** o componente ganha o foco sozinho quando ele começa a receber digitação.
7. O método `campoMascara(String, int, Predicate<String>)` é o responsável por criar o componente de edição. Ele cria um `JFormattedTextField` de acordo com a máscara informada no parâmetro. É neste método que é possível se ver a técnica que usei para fazer ele pular para o campo subsequente sozinho quando a digitação é terminada. Usei uma ***master-power-super-gambeta-plus*** com o `java.awt.Robot` que fica enviando ao sistema operacional um pressionamento da tecla TAB de dentro de um `KeyListener` para pular de campo sempre que ele percebe que o mesmo foi preenchido adequadamente. O parâmetro `posicaoFinal` serve para que ele possa saber em qual posição do texto ele deve pular de campo e o `teste` serve para que ele possa avaliar se o campo foi preenchido corretamente ou não. É importante notar que o TAB só será disparado quando o campo estiver com o *caret* na última posição e isso fará com que ele se torne válido (e é isso que é testado), pois este critério tem que concordar com a situação aonde o `stopCellEditing()` retorna `true` com o campo preenchido.
8. Por fim, os métodos estáticos `campoHora()`, `campoData()` e `campoCpf()` são os responsáveis por criar as `JFormattedTextField` necessárias, especificando para cada caso diferente, a máscara, a posição em que o TAB automático pode ser disparado e o teste para verificar se o preenchimento foi ou não correto.

Finalmente, para completar, a nossa classe principal para poder rodar e testar o nosso programa. Eis o arquivo `TesteJTable.java`:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;

/**
 * @author Victor Stafusa
 */
public class TesteJTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(TesteJTable::rodar);
    }

    private static void rodar() {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("Teste");
        jf.setBounds(20, 20, 500, 200);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        List<MeuElemento> elementos = new ArrayList<>(4);
        elementos.add(new MeuElemento());
        elementos.add(new MeuElemento());
        elementos.add(new MeuElemento());
        elementos.add(new MeuElemento());
        MeuTableModel tm = new MeuTableModel(elementos);
        JTable jt = new JTable(tm);
        jt.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, new MeuCellEditor());
        jt.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new MeuCellRenderer(new ModelCartao()));
        jf.add(jt);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Onde você faz a captura do offset do campo, pra saber que ele já está na ultima posição preenchida e assim mudar para o seguinte? Quebrei a cabeça aqui usando DocumentFilter, PlainDocument e nenhum deu certo kkkk Outro detalhe que notei é que o stopcellEditing é chamado antes do keyListener, ai não consegui identificar também que a pessoa estava apertando tab por este listener antes que a edição fosse parada.

Comment: @diegofm A detecção da posição está no `jftf.getCaretPosition() == posicaoFinal` no `keyTyped`. O valor `posicaoFinal` é 4, 9 ou 13, dependendo do campo (eu poderia ter usado simplesmente `mascara.length() - 1`, mas isso daria errado se aparecesse alguma máscara em que o último caractere é fixo). Para chegar nisso eu também quebrei a cabeça por várias horas tentando usar `PlainDocument`, `FocusListener`, `ActionMap`+`InputMap`. Cheguei a tentar sobreescrever o método `setText`" e experimentei também mais um monte de outras coisas que não deram certo.

Comment: @diegofm E quanto ao `stopCellEditing` vir antes ou depois do `keyTyped`, é importante notar que os dois devem concordar entre si. O `keyTyped` verifica se o campo foi preenchido corretamente e está na última posição antes de mandar o TAB, e o `stopCellEditing` retorna `true` somente se estiver em branco ou preenchido completamente. Assim sendo, para as células relevantes, o `keyTyped` só envia um TAB se, e somente se, o `stopCellEditing` for retornar `true` e o campo não estiver vazio.

Comment: Victor, mas se o stopcellediting retorna true, ele não irá alterar o status de editavel do campo? O problema que tive aqui era que, ao retornar true e checar se tab foi pressionado, ele pulava 2 campos, pq o stopcellediting ao retornar true, pulava pra celula seguinte, ai o keypressed detectava o TAB e pulava mais um.

Comment: @diegofm Não. Quando o `stopCellEditing` retorna `true` ele deixa o usuário sair do campo. Quando retorna `false` o usuário não consegue deixar o campo de edição e é obrigado a ficar editando até que o `stopCellEditing` retorne `true`. Isso não tem relação direta com o fato de um campo ser ou não editável.

Comment: Me expressei mal, era justamente isso que você disse eu quis dizer kkk Então você inverteu a lógica do stopCellEditing, fazendo com que não saia do campo esteja preechido ou vazio?

Comment: @diegofm A lógica dele é não deixar sair do campo se ele estiver preenchido de forma parcial ou incorreta. Isso força o usuário a ou deixar ele em branco ou a preencher de forma correta. De qualquer forma, te convido a testar o meu código. Tomei o cuidado de postar um código completo, compilável, testável e executável, e para isso dei o código completo de todas as minhas classes (incluindo os `imports`) exatamente para que outras pessoas pudessem testar o que fiz.

Comment: Pior que já até testei, mas  eu estava empacando aqui pra entender a lógica toda ali no celleditor. Agora entendi o trecho mais "polemico" que me custou algumas horas aqui ontem hehe. Achei interessante você usar `EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> component.requestFocusInWindow())`, eu estava forçando isso sobreescrevendo o método `changeSelection` da JTable. De qualquer forma, meus parabens, a lógica aplicada no cell editor ficou excelente e flexivel não só ao problema da pergunta, mas a outras adaptações +1 :D

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado mesmo, e parabéns a sua explicação, os métodos que você utilizaram eu conhecia muito pouco, mas além de resolver o problema consegui aprender com ele, devido a isso que você fez. E relaxa, porque a sua "gambiarra" não é pior do que a que eu estava tentando fazer (kkkk) (de sobrescrever a JTable com um FormattedTextField e usar setBounds para transferir de um para outro) novamente, meus parabéns e muito obrigado!